# How to fill selected cells in 3D Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, grid, mplot3d, scatter3d

This should a straight forward question but I could not find the answer, sorry if the question is a duplicate one. Basically I want to fill `Ncell` cells on a 3D grid of `Ngrid x Ngrid x Ngrid`. Below I present a MWE where I just scatter plot the centre (or one corner, it does not matter, I can readjust) of each cell.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ngrid,Ncell=100,150

xx=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
yy=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
zz=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)

%matplotlib widget

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
ax.scatter3D(xx,yy,zz,marker='o',alpha=0.5)
```

Instead of the scatter plot, I need each cell to be filled with a color.
Note that my grid and `Ncell` are much larger than the above values (grid = 1000^3 and `Ncell=` order 10^5), so an efficient code will be very important.
Thank you in advacne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [voxels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html) but it is already slow with your test data:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ngrid,Ncell=100,250

xx=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
yy=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
zz=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
v = np.zeros((Ngrid, Ngrid, Ngrid), dtype=bool)
v[xx, yy, zz] = True

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
ax.voxels(v)
```

I would suggest to use K3D Jupyter and its [voxel](https://k3d-jupyter.org/gallery/showcase/menger-sponge.html). This appears to be much much faster. Note that, as the name suggests, it requires Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import k3d
import numpy as np

Ngrid,Ncell=100,1000

xx=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
yy=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)
zz=np.random.choice(Ngrid,Ncell)

v = np.zeros((Ngrid, Ngrid, Ngrid), dtype=bool)

# NOTE: K3D's voxels works with the the matrix indexing, ij, rather
# then with the cartesian indexing, xy. Read np.meshgrid and run
# some example to understand the differences.
# The bottom line is, the following is the correct indexing:
v[zz, yy, xx] = True

# Once the plot is shown on the screen we can play with options
# by clicking K3D panel -> Objects -> Voxels #1. If we find some
# good options, we can write the values in this command and
# execute it again.
plt_voxels = k3d.voxels(
    v.astype(np.uint8),
    color_map=(0xfdfe03),
    outlines=False, # better hide outlines when setting opacity < 1
    opacity=0.5
)
plot = k3d.plot(grid_visible=False)
plot += plt_voxels

# create scatter
positions = np.vstack([t.flatten() for t in [xx+0.5, yy+0.5, zz+0.5]]).T.astype(np.float32)
plt_points = k3d.points(positions=positions, point_size=0.4, color=0xff0000)
plot += plt_points

plot.display()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It solved the main issue but can I use k3d together with matplotlib? I have to show some points inside the volume. For that I need to change the alpha of the shaded region, plus scatter plot some points. If matplotlib can't be used together with k3d, can I change the transparency in k3d and add a scatter plot?

Comment: You don't need matplotlib for that: K3D is capable of plotting scatters too. I've update the answer. To get acquainted with this library: https://k3d-jupyter.org/gallery/index.html